# Charger block with USBC on both ends not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, battery, charging

I have an MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2021) M1. It is supposed to be chargable with USBC. The power block that comes with it has a cable with megsafe on one side for the macbook and USBC on the other side for plugging into the charging brick.
I bought a better quality high wattage USBC cable, but its not charging. It power source is connected but its not chargin.
I also tried connecting the USB cable to a high performance 65W USB charger with multple slots, tried them all, still no charging.
What could be the problem? I was very happy that USBC for charging is possible as a backup once inevitably the normal port gets stuck pins and such.
What is the best way to go about it? And whats the point to have the megsafe with USBc on the other hand when neither the megsafe cable will accept other USB chargers, nor are other chargers and USBc cables able to charge.

Comment: You’ve kind of lost me with the last half off your post. Could you make an edit to remove all the side questions and opinion “what’s the point” type questions. Summarizing with one and only one question per question usually gets some quick answers. I fear no one will touch this since it’s not sharp on what you seek given that the Apple MagSafe cable does work with any charger and damage to pins is certainly not inevitable over 10 year or more in my experience.

Comment: Would you please supply more information about the cable.  If there's no power supplied to the laptop with that cable then I suspect the cable was damaged or does not comply with the USB specifications, but perhaps I repeated myself as a cable that does not comply with specs as built could be considered damaged.